# How to mock variable in included library

Tags: python, pytest

Folks,

I have a problem during including `file.py` to `test_file.py` namely:

`file.py` uses Robot library `BuiltIn`:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

DEFAULT_IPHY_TTI_TRACE_DIR =
os.path.join(BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${OUTPUT_DIR}'), 'iphy_tti_trace')
```

And when I try to include `file.py` in my `test_file.py`

```
import pytest
#import file.py
```

I receive:

```
test_file.py:8: in <module>
/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py:1331: in get_variable_value
return self._variables[self._get_var_name(name)]
/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py:75: in _variables
return self._namespace.variables
/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py:71: in _namespace
return self._get_context().namespace
/opt/ute/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py:66: in _get_context
raise RobotNotRunningError('Cannot access execution context')
E   RobotNotRunningError: Cannot access execution context
```

How can I mock this? This is posible at all?

Comment: Does `file.py` do some other sort of initialisation that you haven't shown us? Or is that done by something else when you run `file.py` 'normally' e.g. outside of the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the issue is just that you can't mock the `BuiltIn` class where it is used (in `file.py`). You have to mock the class where it is declared (in `robot.libraries.BuiltIn`).

Using [mocks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html):

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock


def _test_default_iphy_tti_trace_dir():
    with patch('robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn.get_variable_value', return_value='/foo/bar'):
        import file
        assert file.DEFAULT_IPHY_TTI_TRACE_DIR == '/foo/bar/iphy_tti_trace'
```

Using [monkeypatch fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html):

```
def test_default_iphy_tti_trace_dir(monkeypatch):
    def mocked_get(self, name):
        return '/foo/bar'

    monkeypatch.setattr('robot.libraries.BuiltIn.BuiltIn.get_variable_value', mocked_get)
    import file
    assert file.DEFAULT_IPHY_TTI_TRACE_DIR == '/foo/bar/iphy_tti_trace'
```

Also note that the mocking is done for the scope of a single test only, so you can't `import file` on top of the test module as the `BuiltIn` will be unpatched there, raising the context error.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling. It's exactly what i looked for.

Comment: Glad I could help!